# Focus lost on Pop-up dialog when browse for File uisng AngularJS pop-up modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

AngularJS boostrap pop-up modal code:

```
    <div class="modal-header">
    <h3 class="modal-title">Add Gallery</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
    <input type="file" id="file1" name="file" class="filestyle" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().AddPhotoGallery(this.files)" data-buttonname="btn-primary" />    
    <span ng-bind="fileValidationMessage" style="color: red;"></span>

    <div ng-show="showFileData || isUpdate">
        <table id="fileTable" class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td ng-if="!isUpdate">File Name</td>
                    <td>Image</td>
                    <td>Message</td>
                    <td>Action</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="obj in fileObjectList">
                    <td ng-if="!isUpdate">{{obj.fileName}}</td>
                    <td><img ng-src="{{obj.fileImageUrl}}" alt="No Profile Picture shows" height="150" width="150" class="img-rounded img-responsive" /></td>
                    <td>{{obj.fileMessage}}</td>
                    <td><input type="button" value="Remove" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="deletePhoto(obj.id)" /></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="button" class="btn1 btn-sm" ng-click="UploadFiles()" value="Upload Gallery" ng-show="isAddImage" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" ng-click="close()">
        Cancel
    </button>
</div>

$scope.AddPhotoGallery = function ($files) {
            $scope.isAddImage = true;
            $scope.galleryValidationMessage = '';
            var isValid = false;
            // Update scenerio $scope.images.length > 0
            if ($scope.images.length > 0 && $scope.images.length < 2) {
                $scope.images.length++;

                angular.forEach($scope.images, function (value, key) {
                    $scope.fileObjectList.push({
                        'id': $scope.fileCnt,
                        'fileMessage': 'File Added to Gallery',
                        'fileName': value.name,
                        'fileData': value
                    })
                    $scope.fileCnt++;                    
                    $scope.isUpdate = true;
                });
            }
            else if ($scope.fileCnt < 2 && $scope.images.length == 0) {
                angular.forEach($files, function (value, key) {
                    isValid = $scope.doFileValidation(value.name);
                    if (isValid) {
                        $scope.fileObjectList.push({ 'id': $scope.fileCnt, 'fileName': value.name, 'fileData': value, 
                            'fileMessage': 'File Added to Gallery '
                        })
                        $scope.fileCnt++;
                    }
                });
            } else {
                $scope.fileValidationMessage = "Cannot add more pictures. ";
            }
            if ($scope.fileCnt > 0) {
                $scope.showFileData = true;
            }
        };
```

Issue:

When I click on browse for adding file the pop-up controller 'AddPhotoGallery' function call and push the data in fileObjectList. Table/Div is bind to 'showFileData' and it is true when fileCnt > 0 (as see in last line of 'AddPhotoGallery' function). The issue is table/div and the data inside it shows only when I click ANYWHERE on the pop-up screen. It seems that focus shifted to last action i.e. file browse dialog and it didn't come back to the pop-up dialog.

More Explanation:

```
if ($scope.fileCnt > 0) {
   $scope.showFileData = true;
}
```

When the $scope.showFileData is true the div/table and the data inside it should show immediately but it is showing when I click ANYWHERE on the modal pop-up. I know the actual cause and that is focus doesn't come back to modal pop-up after browse.

Can anywhere suggest how to get the control/focus back to pop-up modal on after file added using File Browse?

Comment: I'm trying to understand your issue.  Is it that you want the table to NOT show after the file browse dialog box closes?

Comment: No Rani. Let me explain:
if ($scope.fileCnt > 0) {
    $scope.showFileData = true;
}
When file is added using browse 'AddPhotoGallery' function call which will set the $scope.showFileData but the table which is bind to this not show immediately but when I click ANYWHERE on the modal pop-up the table and data inside shows immediately. I know the actual cause and that is focus doesn't come back to modal pop-up after browse.